# Will unittest work for functional (non-object-oriented) program in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm a beginner programmer, I've been stuck for the past week trying to write unit tests.  I read through the unit test docs and watched two long tutorials on implementing unit testing with `Mock`.  The docs refer to mocking classes extensively, but for functions, I'm not sure if I should be using `@patch/with patch`, `patch.dict{}`, `side_effect`, or some other option to mock a function, specifically the argument to a function.

**mymodule.py**

```
def regex():
    '''Runs a regex, creates a dict 'data' and then calls scraper(data)'''

def scraper(data):
    '''scrapes a website and then calls a function which submits data to a db'''
```

I would like to create a test that passes in test data to the function `scraper` .  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can also do unit test using mock for non-object_oriented code.

See example below:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
def a():
    return 10
def b():
    print(a())  
b()
a = MagicMock(return_value=3)
b()
```

And the output is:

```
10
3
```

In the previous example mock is used to fake/mock the function a(), so you can test function b() in isolation, b() is your SUT, without calling a() real implementation. This can be useful for more complex code, specially when function a() relies on data that might not be available in the unit test level.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough examples to really help, but a couple of observations:

- Generally, it's better to structure your code to avoid the need for mocking in tests; to the extent possible, each function should be a self-contained piece of code, which can be called separately.
- There's no need to mock arguments; simply pass the test value in.
- I'm not sure what's intended with this code:

  ```py
  bar = {'key': 'value'}     

  def foo(bar):
      pass
  ```

  The `bar` defined at the outer level is a completely separate variable to the `bar` used as an argument in the function definition. It is confusing to give them the same name...
- A function can be mocked using `patch` or `patch.object` with the `return_value=...` option; often, though, it suggests that the code needs to be refactored to reduce the dependency between the two functions.

Comment: I appreciate your response, I'm going to clarify the question, versus elaborating here.

Comment: Right, so in the test you call: `scraper(test_data)`

No need to mock.

Comment: Ok, I must have another bug somewhere, but I'll troubleshoot and leave it for another post as needed.  Thank you.